how fit a polynomial function in gnuplot?
I've been stuck for one week in this problem and I don't know what function fits better with my data. I've used gnuplot to fit a function to my data. I've tried a lot of combinations of functions, for example, polynomial with trigonometric functions, logarithmic functions with polynomial functions. I'm tired because neither combination fits my data points well and the best fit that I've made so far is with:
 f(x) = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d
gnuplot> a = 1
gnuplot> b = 1
gnuplot> c = 1
gnuplot> d = 0.1
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-6
gnuplot> fit f(x) '1m4.txt' using 1:2:3 yerrors via a, b, c, d

type After 7 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 4.19537
rel. change during last iteration : -8.21081e-07

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 5
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 0.91601
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 0.839074
p-value of the Chisq distribution (FIT_P)              : 0.521644

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -466.914         +/- 232          (49.69%)
b               = 55.6287          +/- 27.5         (49.44%)
c               = -0.968304        +/- 0.4464       (46.1%)
d               = 0.136259         +/- 0.0008638    (0.6339%)here

but yes, it is a bad fit, i know that the parameters than relate with a good fit is reduced chisquare aprox 1, p-value aprox 0.05 and small asymptotic standars errors. I need help please my dataset is:
1/steps           prob of return             standar error                    prob of no return
0.1                0.1288                        0.002946                           0.8712
0.02               0.1355                        0.001940                           0.8645
0.01               0.1313                        0.002018                           0.8687
0.002              0.1348                        0.002224                           0.8652
0.001              0.1366                        0.002418                           0.8633
0.0002             0.1398                        0.002382                           0.8602
0.0001             0.1361                        0.001987                           0.8639
0.00002            0.1350                        0.001812                           0.8650
0.00001            0.1342                        0.002100                           0.8658

this data is about of random walkers in 5-dimensiones their probability of return to origin with its standard error, I only used first 3 columns. the next image show the plot of my dataset:

I've checking a lot of times gnuplot's manual but I'm stuck.

What do you actually want to achieve? Plotting a line which guides the eye through the datapoints?
The purpose of fitting is to find the parameters (for a given function) which reproduce your data the best. However, for this, you first need a theoretical model which dictates you the type of function f(x) you should fit to. You can basically fit anything to a n-th degree polynomial function.
